# How to check null class in C++

Tags: c++, class, null

How do I check if a class is null or not in C++? Suppose I have class `Line`:

```
Line line[1000];

if (line[0] == NULL)
   cout << "NULL";
else
   cout << "NOT NULL";
```

I get this error message:

> no match for 'operator=' in 'line[i] = 0'

Comment: Your code shows ==, but you say the error is = ?

Comment: that just a small part of my code

Comment: Yes, BUT: the error specifies operator=, your code shows == (which would be operator==. These are not the same, and the error does not match the code.

Comment: So you post only an irrelevant part of your code and you expect us to do... what exactly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code

```
Line line[1000];
```

creates 1000 Line objects and stores them in the line array. The test against NULL makes no sense. You could define

```
Line* line[1000];
```

In that case you need to initialize the array and your test would work.

Comment: what is different with Line* line[1000] and Line *line[1000]

Comment: Style. If you stick with the latter, then it looks better when you do things like `char *begin, *end`

Comment: It's worth noting perhaps that you should not really be doing a comparison with NULL for pointers anyway, you should instead be doing `if (ptr == 0)`, which is safer according to some coding standards (I think NULL can be implementation dependent).

Comment: @icabod: You couldn't be more wrong. It is as safe to compare with NULL as it is with 0, even if on some implementations the value of a null pointer isn't actually all 0 bits

Comment: NULL is an ancient word hahahaha :-)

Comment: @ mkb: If you stick with the first one then it look more like C++ code where type is more important. You are correct though that your statement does not work so well, but then again since it is basically banned in every set of coding rules I have ever seen as diabolic bad practice it does not really matter.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I was referring to, for example, the High Integrity C++ standard (http://www.codingstandard.com/HICPPCM/High_Integrity_CPP_Rule_14.16.html), but that does in fact reference integrating with C from C++. Hey, I've being doing HICPP recently :)

Answer (score 11):

I am guessing you are from a .NET or Java background. An object of class type cannot be NULL in C++. If you stored an array of *pointers* to Line, it would be another thing and your syntax would be valid.

Now, if you have your own semantics as to what a NULL Line is , you can

- Implement a member function called `IsNull()`
- Overload the `operator void*` and check `if(Lines[i])`

Comment: @Nawaz: Where's the actual +1 ? :D (Not that I care, I've hit the cap, but anyway :))

Comment: Oops.. I forgot that :P..Now +1. :D

Answer (score 1):

Pointer to an instance can be NULL not class instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your Line class is not NULL.  You have 1000 instances of Line, created by the default constructor.  Arguably, you could test NULL using `Line & operator == (const int ) const`, and then compare some internal members, but that is odd to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Line is not pointer . Whenever you writes. `Line line[1000];`

```
1000 of line get allocated.
```

So after that line not be NULL.

Comment: yes. you are missing c/c++  great feature if you are not knowing pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Section 5.17 of the ISO standard says

> There are several assignment
>   operators, all of which group
>   right-to-left. All require a
>   modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand, and the type of an assignment
>   expression is that of its left
>   operand. The result of the assignment
>   operation is the value stored in the
>   left operand after the assignment has
>   taken place; the result is an lvalue.

It is because the overloaded operator for the '=' does not match any of your provided overloaded instances.

You need to initialize it as Line * not simply Line and it should work. Better if you overload void* (e.g. new).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, `line[0]` has the type `Line&`, which can be read as a `reference to a Line object`. In C++, references cannot be `NULL`.

The error message in your question appears to be from a line of code that you have not posted. I can only speculate based on the error message that you are attempting to assign the value `0` to the line object located at index `i`. Because the `=` operator is not overloaded in your `Line` class, the compiler is unable to resolve the difference in types.